# Regular expression to remove a set of characters from innerHTML contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm working on a contenteditable innerHTML string in JavaScript and tried to remove pairs of

```
<div><br></div>
```

It appears when user presses Enter for a newline.

Example String : (will be dynamic)

```
<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div>Example <br> String d<<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div></div>
```

so I can get

```
Example <br> String d<
```

I tried my regex by searching Stack Overflow too:

```
let final_text = document.getElementById('chat_room_input_box').innerHTML.trim();

final_text = final_text.replace(/^\s*(?:<br\s*\/?\s*>)+|(?:<br\s*\/?\s*>)+\s*$/gi, '');
final_text = final_text.replace(/^(?:&nbsp;|\s)+|(?:&nbsp;|\s)+$/ig,''); 
final_text = final_text.replace(/^\s*(?:<div\s*\/?\s*>)+|(?:<div\s*\/?\s*>)+\s*$/gi, '');
```

I can remove `<br>` or `&nbsp;` at start/ end but fails to remove `<div><br></div>`

Comment: This sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378); a problem that might be better solved a different way than you're asking for. In general, parsing HTML with RegEx is *highly* discouraged, unless you know *exactly* what that HTML will look like in all situations (and even then it can still be dicey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex to handle HTML. Regex is not powerful enough for this.

Use an HTML parser. Luckily the world's most capable HTML parser is right at your finger tips - a browser. All that is necessary to parse a piece of HTML is to set an element's `.innerHTML` property.

Then you can easily remove any elements you define, for example `<div>` that are empty - which includes those that only contain `<br>` and/or whitespace.

As a bonus, you even are guaranteed to get valid HTML back from the operation, so the invalid `String d<` will be returned as the valid `String d&lt;`.

```js
function sanitizeHtml(html) {
    const container = document.createElement('DIV');
    // Step 1: Parse the HMTL
    container.innerHTML = html;

    // Step 2: Modify the structure
    for (let div of container.querySelectorAll('div')) {
        if (div.textContent.trim() === '') div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        // ...over time, I'm sure you'll find more things you'd like to correct
    }

    // Step 3: return the modified HTML
    return container.innerHTML;
}

function showResult() {
    const result = sanitizeHtml(this.innerHTML);
    document.getElementById('outputHtml').textContent = result;
    document.getElementById('outputDisplay').innerHTML = result;
}

const input = document.getElementById('input');
input.contentEditable = true;
input.addEventListener('input', showResult);

showResult.call(input);
```

```css
#input, #outputDisplay {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#outputHtml {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="input"><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div>Example <br> String d<<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div></div></div>
<pre id="outputHtml"></pre>
<div id="outputDisplay"></pre>
```

Comment: @Vincentius For the sake of it, I've made the code snippet interactive, it now updates the output HTML as you type into the contentEditable.

Answer (score 0):

so, by what I see, it would make sense to do it in steps

first remove elements like `br` (self closing) elements

```js
str="<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div>Example String d<<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div></div>"

############## REMOVING SELF CLOSING ELEMENTS
# here is a list of self closing elements, you can add more that you want to remove
str = str.replace(/<(br|img)>/g, "")

# another way of removing self closing elements, is to look for the closure when they are properly coded <br />
str = str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, "")

# if wanted, you can use both
str = str.replace(/(<br\s*\/?>|<(br|img)>)/g, "")

########## REMOVE ELEMENTS THAT CLOSE EMPTY (divs)
str = str.replace(/<([^>]*)>\s*<\/\1>/g, "")

# this will return
# str = str.replace(/<([^>])>\s*<\/\1>/g, "")
```

If what you want it to look for specific elements, you can use

```js
str = str.replace(/<\/?\s*(br|img|div)\s*\/?>/g, "")

## this returns
"Example String d<"
```

To learn more, I recomend
https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html
https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/